# Postgres psql \i seems to be adding a semicolon

Tags: postgresql, psql, eof

I am teaching a SQL class using postgres.  One of my students found something that I do not understand.

The student is submitting multiple queries in an ascii file to psql using the `\i` command  (i.e.: `\i /temp/query.txt`)

Some students omitted the semicolon after the last command - but they still got a valid output from the file.

IE `psql` behaves is if it appends a semicolon to the end of file.

Does Postgres accept either a semicolon or an EOF as the end of a command - or is there something else going on here?

(I have seen this on Windows.  Have not looked under Unix as yet)  Postgres V 13.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From source `src/bin/psql/mainloop.c`:

```
/*
 * If we have a non-semicolon-terminated query at the end of file, we
 * process it unless the input source is interactive --- in that case it
 * seems better to go ahead and quit.  Also skip if this is an error exit.
 */
```